# Storyboards and subclasses

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I've been working in iOS for a bit but have mostly worked on a project that never used storyboards. Everything is in code, and I'm not too experienced with Storyboards.

I'm trying to understand how to implement a `BaseTableViewController` and have all my table view controllers subclass that. I want to keep one `tableView` in this superclass.

So say I create `FirstTableViewController` and `SecondTableViewController` subclasses off of `BaseTableViewController`. I add tableViews to each so that I can set my Protoype Cells for each distinctive subclass. Then I add and connect these in my storyboard.

Where I'm confused is that now I have tableViews in the storyboard for each subclass VC, but then I want to keep the superclass tableView as the only tableView.

How to reconcile this?

Comment: Could you clarify one point? You are trying to make subclassed tableViewControllers but not have tableViews in them, just one in the BaseTableViewController?

Comment: Yes. This is how I setup my project when in pure code. But I'm confused about how to handle the Prototype Cells in storyboard if setup this way.

Comment: How did you do this in code? When you say one table view, do you mean just one instance? A view can't be in more than one place at a time, so how were you doing that?

Comment: Hmmm a tableViewController is made to show tableViews. Maybe you want to create multiple objects (instantiated classes) of one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you place your table view prototype cell in a Xib file instead of placing them in the storyboard prototype. That way you do not have to create the tableviews in your BaseTableView subclasses. You register the table view cells in the viewdidload of the Tableview controller subclasses using code like this

```
     let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "xibfileforTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
     tableView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
```

You can still use outlets from the xib files just like storyboards